# Web.config file IIS rules for URL rewrites for Angular hosted inside ASP.NET Core not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to get the IIS web.config rule rewrites to work but I have been unsuccessful thus far. Based on my research I need a single web.config file at the root of the main project.

[image]

The contents of this web.config file are as follow:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="SpaRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>`
```

I have already installed the IIS Rewrite module. Based on this set up my expectation is that:

1. Once angular app is initially loaded, I would be able to refresh the page successfully - this is not the case

I have found a work around for this to add the following code in Startup.cs:

```
.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    await next();
                    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                    {
                        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                        await next();
                    }
                });
```

This however feels hacky, unless this is the accepted way of doing it now?

What is the right way of handling this?

Thanks

Comment: Do use FRT to learn how the rules are being executed, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the angular routes rule which is hosted as an application and added this at the root web.config:

```
<rule name="ARoutes" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="testapi" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:843/testapi/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
          </rule>
```

in short, you need to provide the full URL of the rewritten page.

and you want to use at the application level than you need to create a web.config file in the angular site dist folder.

[image]

and add below code in web.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

        <rule name="AngularJS Routes1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>


    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```